# Remove empty row from array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I try to remove empty lines or values in an array, for example if the output of $DBLevel is empty, the hole line should be removed. Is there a easy way to to this?

thanks

```
$vmname= "srvsql009"
$DBType = "sql"
$DBLevel = ""
$style = "blue"


$myCol = @()

 $x = "" | Select 'Name','DB-Type','DB-Level','Style'
 $x.Name = $vmname
 $x.'DB-Type' = $DBType
 $x.'DB-Level' = $DBLevel
 $x.'Style' = $style
 

 $myCol += $x 



 $myCol
```

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType

---

True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Comment: There is no `$ITLevel` in your code.. If you want a collection from which you later decide to remove elements from, I would advise using a [System.Collections.Generic.List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1), or simply do not add to the array if the condition is not met.

Comment: hey sorry, copy and paste failure. Now the code is correct.

Comment: this is part of an workflow and sometimes it could happen that the variables will be empty like this example

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you had results like this in your `$myCol` variable.

```
PS> $myCol

Name      DB-Type   DB-Level Style
----      -------   -------- -----
srvsql009 sql                blue 
SQLSRV200 cosmos    ALPHA    RED
```

You can filter items in an array using the `Where-Object` command, like this:

```
PS>  $myCol | Where DB-Level -ne ""

Name      DB-Type DB-Level Style
----      ------- -------- -----
SQLSRV200 cosmos  ALPHA    RED
```

PowerShell comparison operators are different from most every other programming language, meaning you can't use `==` to compare equals, or `<=` for less than or equal to operations.

To learn more about the comparison operators, [check out this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I know, but it could be that for example in the next run "Style" is empty, so this will not work. In the array, there will never more than one Server, if this makes easier

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment,

Removing elements from a simple array (`Object[]`) is both time and memory consuming because an array is of fixed length and when you remove an element, the whole array needs to be rebuilt in memory.

If you have a collection you need to be able to remove items from, better make use of a `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`

Example collection (following your syntax)

```
$vmname  = "srvsql009"
$DBType  = "sql"
$DBLevel = 120
$style   = "blue"

$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    $x = "" | Select 'Name','DB-Type','DB-Level','Style'
    $x.Name       = 'srvsql{0:D3}' -f ([int]$vmname.Substring(6) + $i) # for demo, increment the number
    $x.'DB-Type'  = $DBType
    $x.'DB-Level' = if ($i -eq 3) {$null} else {$DBLevel + $i}  # for demo add an object with empty 'DB-Level'
    $x.'Style'    = $style
    # add this object to the list
    $list.Add($x)
}
```

`$list` now contains

```
Name      DB-Type DB-Level Style
----      ------- -------- -----
srvsql009 sql          120 blue 
srvsql010 sql          121 blue 
srvsql011 sql          122 blue 
srvsql012 sql          123 blue 
srvsql013 sql          124 blue
```

Now, if you want to remove one of the items in this list, you can do that using its index:

```
$list.RemoveAt(2)  # removes item 'srvsql011'
```

Result:

```
Name      DB-Type DB-Level Style
----      ------- -------- -----
srvsql009 sql          120 blue 
srvsql010 sql          121 blue 
srvsql012 sql              blue 
srvsql013 sql          124 blue
```

Or remove by determining the object to delete:

```
$x = $list | Where-Object { !$_.'DB-Level' }
$list.Remove($x)
```

Result:

```
Name      DB-Type DB-Level Style
----      ------- -------- -----
srvsql009 sql          120 blue 
srvsql010 sql          121 blue 
srvsql011 sql          122 blue 
srvsql013 sql          124 blue
```